# React-native-maps Crash on iOS on zoom out

Tags: react-native, google-maps-sdk-ios, react-native-maps

I am facing the same issue and reproducible in react-native-maps:0.27.1 and pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils','~> 3.4.0'.

Below are the crash logs for the issue:

`Incirclegmscore::vector::GMSMarkupPolygonInstance::CreateEntities(gmscore::base::reffed_ptrgmscore::vector::Camera const&, gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*, objc_object objcproto18GMSEntityResources*, gmscore::renderer::ProxySortedRenderBin<std::__1::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned int, gmscore::base::reffed_ptrgmscore::renderer::BaseEntity >, gmscore::renderer::ProxySortedRenderBin::lessgmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::BaseEntity > >, gmscore::renderer::Behavior, char const* const&) Incirclegmscore::vector::GMSMarkupMultiZoomLinesInstance::UpdateEntities(float, gmscore::base::reffed_ptrgmscore::vector::Camera, gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*, objc_object objcproto18GMSEntityResources*, gmscore::renderer::ProxySortedRenderBin<std::__1::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned int, gmscore::base::reffed_ptrgmscore::renderer::BaseEntity >, gmscore::renderer::ProxySortedRenderBin::lessgmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::BaseEntity > >, gmscore::renderer::Behavior, char const* const&) Incirclegmscore::vector::GMSMarkupBehavior::UpdateInstanceMap(std::__1::map<unsigned long, gmscore::base::reffed_ptrgmscore::vector::GMSMarkupInstance, std::__1::less, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<unsigned long const, gmscore::base::reffed_ptrgmscore::vector::GMSMarkupInstance > > > const&, gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*, bool) Incirclegmscore::vector::GMSMarkupBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) Incirclegmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer::Draw(bool) Incircle-[GMSPhoenixRenderer drawForced:] Incircle-[GMSEntityRendererView draw] Incircle-[GMSVectorMapView draw] Incircle-[GMSEntityRendererView displayLinkFired:] Incircle-[GMSDisplayLink displayLinkFired:]`